# Compiling a python project

Tags: python, web-applications, desktop-application

I am sorry if this isn't the right place to ask such a question. If it's the case mods can remove my question.

I dont have a CS background but I am working on a python project for which I have to import many libraries (numpy, pandas, kiras, scikitlearn, etc).

My question is, how can I compile my project into a decent application with a GUI? And is it possible for the application to work on another device on which there is no python and of course no libraries installed.

Again, I am sorry If this is inappropriate of me.

Comment: not inappropriate to ask, so much so as the answer would be too broad to even begin to fit here (and so, is not a good fit for this site). However, here's some better ways to think of the problem: 1. regarding GUI, you need to make the GUI in python or have some other language communicate with python where the GUI is made. 2. Regarding working on another device, the key word for this is called "executable" programs. Both exist in python, there's libraries to make GUIs, and libraries to make python packages into executable files.

Comment: So making the app executable means it can run on any other device without it having any of the libraries?

Comment: aye, something like that. See what you can find out about it online.